Codeium completes text string with HTML tag
I am using the Codeium plugin in Jetbrain's PHPStorm.  When I'm writing a string of text, like between <p> tags on a PHP web page, it will suggest the rest of the string.  When I hit tab to accept that suggestion, it will often make the previous or next word an HTML tag, which is wrong.  What's the solution to keep this from happening?
